# WHat would be a proper way to require modules

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Consider the following requirejs config:

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 10,
    baseUrl: 'js/libs',
    paths: {
        'jQuery'            : 'jquery',
        'jQueryUi'          : 'jquery.ui',
        'cookie'            : 'jquery.cookie',
        'underscore'        : 'underscore',
        'backbone'          : 'backbone',
        'text'              : 'text',
        'reusable'          : '../../tmpl/reusable.tmpl.html'
    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery':{
            exports: '$'
        },
        'cookie':['jQuery'],
        'jQueryUi':['jQuery'],
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone':{
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
require(['cookie','jQueryUi'],function(){
    require(['backbone'],function(){
        this._templates = {};
        require(['text!reusable'],function(reusable){
            this._templates['reusable'] = reusable;
        });
    });
});
```

Everything works as expected so far...

Contents of some_module.js:

```
define(function(){
    var init = function(){
        console.log('some_module initialized');
    };
    return{
        init:init
    };
});
```

Based on the Backbone router navigate function, `some_module` is required at a certain point like so:

```
require(['some_module'],function(module){
    module.init();
});
```

On route change, a similar module is called the same way.

When navigating, the user may return to the previous route, meaning that `some_module` is requested again, this time from the `cache` since `some_module.js` was stored there on the first call.

Question:

Since `some_module` can be requested once, or multiple times, is it a good practice to load the module every time, even if the file is cached ?... or initially set it in the global scope:

```
var some_module = require('some_module');
```

and each time the module is needed, just call:

```
some_module.init()
```

or whatever property it may return?

What would be the difference when it comes to memory leaks, and general application functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that everything you load through RequireJS is **loaded once and only once**.

The first time the module is needed (due to `require` or a `define` that has the module as a dependency), it will be actually fetched from the network and then its factory function will be executed. (The factory is the function that you give to `define`.) The result of the factory function is cached by RequireJS.

When the module is needed *again*, the module is returned from RequireJS cache without using the browser's cache of files or going to the network.

Comment: So defining it to the global scope is a NO NO... Very useful insight. Thought that once loaded, the module would be called every time from the browser cache. Thank you.

Comment: I certainly would never leak a module to the global scope as part of normal operations.